# Multithreading with duplicate matrixes? [critique/insight wanted]

Tags: design, multithreading, computer-vision

I'm working on a video streaming project for drones with opencv where I want to apply multiple stacked image manipulations on a 2D input matrix. I was advised to make all manipulations calls non-blocking.

In designing this I had the idea to give each of the manipulations a thread and 2 matrixes, the last completed matrix and the currently working matrix.

This way the manipulation after the currentmanipulation can access the last completed matrix and do it's own processing, even if it was an older image, you still get the newest data from that manipulation.

This seems like it would work but will cause an overhead due to the possibility of a manipulation being in the middle of an operation when new data is available.

In this project, each of the previous manipulations should be completed before the next manipulation can happen, there is however also the need for low latency.

Is there a benefit to doing this over a queue/blocking operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantage of threading is that you can get a pipeline of processing stages going.  On a multi-core processor, this can allow you to have several steps running *at the same time*, each processing the output of the pervious step.

But if some steps take longer than others, then you can't really get around that.  The faster ones will just have to wait until the slower ones are done.  And each step can only start once the previous one has finished an image.

Using the last completed image may help in some cases, but not if you just keep applying the next step over and over again to the same image.

Comment: Yes, I initially thought having the last image always accessible would help if there's external data streams changing things on the images. But it's most likely the images and not the textual data the program will be waiting for so having those streaming through the pipeline is probably a higher priority. Yes to pipes and threading, no to duplicate images.